# how to set index in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my Htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It's just delete the .php from the URL but when I go to mydomain.com/index (index.php) or mydomain.com/ it's show me 404 error, why is that?

Comment: you want to delivery the directory or file, then try to add right below your `RewriteCond` another condition > `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`    
I push all request to an index.php file and route everything from there doing like this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]`

Answer (score -3):

I found this little piece of Code.
You should change yourfile.html to the name of your Index Filename.

DirectoryIndex yourfile.html